# Dropdown with 4 Levels identical selections

Tags: javascript, forms, select, dropdown

I've this modified script I found online.

It works very well to have dropdown select menu with 4 posiblities.

The problem here. If a menu is identical like here with Mexico (for Mexico the city and Mexico the country), it won't work correctly.

How i can correct that? Thanks for help!

```js
var categories = [];

// list1

categories["startList"] = ["America","Europe"]

// list2

categories["America"] = ["USA","Mexico"];
categories["Europe"] = ["France","UK"];

// list3

categories["USA"] = ["New York","Texas"];;
categories["Mexico"] = ["Mexico","Guadalajara"];
categories["France"] = ["Alsace","Normandie"];
categories["UK"] = ["Wales", "Scotland", "England"];

// list4

categories["New York"] = ["Manhattan","Brooklyn","Harlem","Queens"];
categories["Texas"] = ["Dallas","Eagle Pass"];

categories["Mexico"] = ["DF"];
categories["Guadalaraja"] = ["East","West"];

categories["Alsace"] = ["Strasbourg","Kronenbourg"];
categories["Normandie"] = ["Caen","Saint-Malo","Saint-Pierre","Saint-Jean"];

categories["Wales"] = ["Cardiff", "New Port"];
categories["Scotland"] = ["Edimbourg"];
categories["England"] = ["London","Manchester","Exeter","Dover"];



var nLists = 4; // number of select lists in the set

function fillSelect(currCat,currList){
var step = Number(currList.name.replace(/\D/g,""));
for (i=step; i<nLists+1; i++) {
document.forms['tripleplay']['List'+i].length = 1;
document.forms['tripleplay']['List'+i].selectedIndex = 0;
}
var nCat = categories[currCat];
for (each in nCat) {
var nOption = document.createElement('option'); 
var nData = document.createTextNode(nCat[each]); 
nOption.setAttribute('value',nCat[each]); 
nOption.appendChild(nData); 
currList.appendChild(nOption); 
} 
} 

function init() {
fillSelect('startList',document.forms['tripleplay']['List1'])
}

navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer" ? attachEvent('onload', init, false) : addEventListener('load', init, false);
```

```html
<form name="tripleplay" action="">
<select name='List1' onchange="fillSelect(this.value,this.form['List2'])">
<option selected>Select One</option>
</select>
&nbsp;
<select name='List2' onchange="fillSelect(this.value,this.form['List3'])">
<option selected>Select Two</option>
</select>
&nbsp;
<select name='List3' onchange="fillSelect(this.value, this.form['List4'])">
<option selected >Select Three</option>
</select>
&nbsp;
<select name='List4' onchange="getValue(this.value, this.form['List3'].value, this.form['List2'].value, 
this.form['List1'].value)">
<option selected >Select Four</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Original adaptation of https://jsfiddle.net/nbz9atmv/ and https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/country-state-city-dropdown-list/2438

Comment: I'm not sure it will fix the issue, but `categories` should definitely be a [literal object](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object) and not an array. `var categories = {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed a few errors from this snippet.

I would say instead of declaring the city in Mexico as 'Mexico', why not declare it as 'Mexico City'? From what I understand this is what the city is formally recognized as and your code will recognize this as well. So, I changed 'Mexico' the city to 'Mexico City' and it worked perfectly well. This also allows your resulting code to be understood more easily by your target audience.

The second error I noticed was you had 'Guadalajara' spelled incorrectly in 'list 4'.

Also, you had getValue for the list4 select. Removed and changed to this.value. If you need to grab the value simply call the id using JS, if that was your intention.

*the replace() will throw an eror but it still works properly as it sitll continues to refrain from multiple values being added to the final dropdown(list4) if changes are made to the previous dropdown(list3).*

Below is the code running correctly.

Let me know if this helped!

```js
var categories = [];

// list1

categories["startList"] = ["America","Europe"]

// list2

categories["America"] = ["USA","Mexico"];
categories["Europe"] = ["France","UK"];

// list3

categories["USA"] = ["New York","Texas"];;
categories["Mexico"] = ["Mexico City","Guadalajara"];
categories["France"] = ["Alsace","Normandy"];
categories["UK"] = ["Wales", "Scotland", "England"];

// list4

categories["New York"] = ["Manhattan","Brooklyn","Harlem","Queens"];
categories["Texas"] = ["Dallas","Eagle Pass"];

categories["Mexico City"] = ["DF"];
categories["Guadalajara"] = ["East","West"];

categories["Alsace"] = ["Strasbourg","Kronenbourg"];
categories["Normandy"] = ["Caen","Saint-Malo","Saint-Pierre","Saint-Jean"];

categories["Wales"] = ["Cardiff", "New Port"];
categories["Scotland"] = ["Edimbourg"];
categories["England"] = ["London","Manchester","Exeter","Dover"];



var nLists = 4; // number of select lists in the set

function fillSelect(currCat,currList){
var step = Number(currList.name.replace(/\D/g,""));

for (i=step; i<nLists+1; i++) {
document.forms['tripleplay']['List'+i].length = 1;
document.forms['tripleplay']['List'+i].selectedIndex = 0;
}
var nCat = categories[currCat];
for (each in nCat) {
var nOption = document.createElement('option'); 
var nData = document.createTextNode(nCat[each]); 
nOption.setAttribute('value',nCat[each]); 
nOption.appendChild(nData); 
currList.appendChild(nOption); 
} 
} 

function init() {
fillSelect('startList',document.forms['tripleplay']['List1'])
}

navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer" ? attachEvent('onload', init, false) : addEventListener('load', init, false);
```

```html
<form name="tripleplay" action="">
<select name='List1' onchange="fillSelect(this.value,this.form['List2'])">
<option selected>Select One</option>
</select>
&nbsp;
<select name='List2' onchange="fillSelect(this.value,this.form['List3'])">
<option selected>Select Two</option>
</select>
&nbsp;
<select name='List3' onchange="fillSelect(this.value, this.form['List4'])">
<option selected >Select Three</option>
</select>
&nbsp;
<select name='List4' onchange="fillSelect(this.value, this.form['List3'].value, this.form['List2'].value, 
this.form['List1'].value)">
<option selected >Select Four</option>
</select>
</form>
```